# How to get key, or key name, from keyCode without an event

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert a `keyCode` to its key name in JavaScript. For example, a `keyDown` event includes these properties in Chrome:

```
key: "Control"
keyCode: 17
```

I have a `keyCode` and want to get its `key`, but not inside of a `keyDown` event. Is there a function that can do this? Here are some examples of inputs and outputs:

```
65 -> a
186 -> ;
13 -> Enter
39 -> ArrowRight
```

Thanks!

Comment: Here's the list: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UI_Events/Keyboard_event_key_values

Comment: Thanks, I could make a dictionary but I'm hoping there's a function that converts it, kind of like `String.fromCharCode`